# How to use Doctrine Extension

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, doctrine-query

Can anybody please say to me, how i can use Doctrine Extension? I see in DoctrineExtensions folder file Field.php, how i can use its functionality to set ORDER BY FIELD(id, 2,1,3), for example?

My query:

```
 $queryBuilder->select("t")->from('\Common\Model\Entity\Ticket', "t")->where("t.id IN (282,283,281)")
            ->addOrderBy('FIELD(t.id,' . implode(',', array(282,283,281)) . ')');
```

I am got error:

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 86: Error: Expected end of string, got '('
```

But it does not work. A lot of thanks and sorry for my poor english.

And it is not duplicate. I want to cnow HOW i can (what i myst do) to use Field.php Doctrine Extension

Comment: Please improve your question by posting all relevant **error messages** exactly as they appear.

Answer (score 0):

Debug your full query with this:

```
$queryBuilder->select("t")->from('\Common\Model\Entity\Ticket', "t")->where("t.id IN (282,283,281)")
        ->addOrderBy('FIELD(t.id,' . implode(',', array(282,283,281)) . ')');
print $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getSQL();
die();
```

And output your full query for more analysis, please.

Comment: Victor, please, check out my question. I am got error on FIRST line...  I am cant getQuery() , or getQuery()->getResult()... I want to know what i must do to use Doctrine Extension called Field.php in DoctrineExtensions folder...